# How to save a model in django when some of the fields are populated by a sequence in oracle?

Tags: django, oracle, forms, model, save

I have a model MyModel in django one of whose fields gets a value from a sequence upon insert into Oracle 12c. So I do

```
myModel = MyModel(field1=123,field2='abc')
myModel.save()
```

The problem is that field1 gets its value upon insert into the Oracle database. If I omit the field then try to save I get ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL. There's no way I can give the field a value in django, either. How do I save the model? Thanks.

Comment: Is your `field1` defined as an `AutoField`?

Comment: all my fields were generated by running inspectdb, because I am working with a legacy database.

Comment: So, your field was mapped as an `IntegerField`?

Comment: yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your `field1` to an `AutoField`, so every time you save a new object Oracle will assign the consecutive value.

```
field1 = models.AutoField()
```

If this is your primary key then pass the `primary_key=True` argument to the `AutoField` constructor.

**UPDATE**

When using legacy databases, you have to remove the mapped fields that are sequences in the database, so Django does the work of finding the way to work with those fields.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. After changing my model to use Autofield still having problems. When I create an instance of myModel, I tried omitting field1 thus:   myModel = Model(field2='abc')  but am still getting the ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL error.

Comment: Is your field an ID?, I mean, if it is, just remove it from the model. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41591660/6855686

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I am glad to help, Please upvote my answer, you know... It helps.